# Probability of withdrawal from university

Tags: probability

Consider the population of students attending a university.  Suppose that **64%** of these students are from Town O, **15%** are from Town K, and **21%** are from Town T.  Of all the students from Town O, **8%** eventually withdraw from their program.  The withdrawal rates for students from Town K and Town T are **22%** and **13%**, respectively.
Suppose a student from the university does withdraw from their program. What is the probability that the student is from Town O?

I solved for the probability that a randomly selected student will withdraw, which is **0.1115** and it is correct. I tried **P(O|W)= P*(O∩W) / P(O) = 0.08 / 0.1115 = 0.7175** , but this does not match the answer of **0.4592**.

Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT: Should be **P(O|W)= P*(O∩W) / P(W)**, sorry for the typo.

Comment: Your formula is incorrect.  $P(O|W) = P(O \cap W)/\mathbf{P(W)}$. Note that you'll have to calculate $P(W)$ from the data given. For this, use the [total probability law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine 10000 students.  .64(10000)= 6400 of them are from town O and .08(6400)= 512 withdraw. .15(10000)= 1500 are from town K and .22(1500)= 330 withdraw.  .21(10000)= 2100 are from town T and .13(2100)= 273 a withdraw.

So a total of 512+ 330+ 273= 1115 students withdraw (and 1115 out of 10000 is, as you say 0.0115) and 512 of them, or 512/1115= 0.4592, are from town O.

You used .08 which is the percentage of students from town O without regard that to the number of students from town O- the number of students from the various towns is not the same.

Comment: Thank you very much, it makes sense to me now.